# Avoiding reading out the blob

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blob

I am currently trying to use data from a blob to process this data and then send it via email. As of now I am receiving the following error - my guess is that it relates to the size of the blob that I read into memory, since it only happens with bigger blobs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
  return route.handler_adapter(request, response)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/base/data/home/apps/xxxx/main.py", line 154, in post
db.run_in_transaction(filtering)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 2461, in RunInTransaction
return RunInTransactionOptions(None, function, *args, **kwargs)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 2599, in RunInTransactionOptions
ok, result = _DoOneTry(new_connection, function, args, kwargs)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 2621, in _DoOneTry
result = function(*args, **kwargs)

File "/base/data/home/apps/xxxx/main.py", line 128, in filtering
for k in liwkws:

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2326, in next
return self.__model_class.from_entity(self.__iterator.next())

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2892, in next
next_batch = self.__batcher.next()

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2754, in next
return self.next_batch(self.AT_LEAST_ONE)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2791, in next_batch
batch = self.__next_batch.get_result()

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
return self.__get_result_hook(self)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2528, in __query_result_hook
self._batch_shared.conn.check_rpc_success(rpc)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1224, in check_rpc_success
raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
BadRequestError: invalid handle: 16023202376614806719
```

This is the code:

```
    #Reads in all the variables from former process

    filter_name = self.request.get('filter_name')
    user = self.request.get('user')
    lowkey = self.request.get('lowkey')

    def filtering():

            # This is where I read the Blob into memory

        low = blobstore.BlobReader(lowkey).read()
        liwkws = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM FilterList WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1", filter_key(filter_name))

            # Preparing the data for processing

            low = unicode(low, 'utf8').encode('utf-8').replace('\r', '').split('\n')

        for j in range(len(low)):
            for k in liwkws:
                if k.newkey.encode('utf-8').lower() in low[j].lower(): 
                    low[j] = 'delete'

        cuent = low.count('delete')

        for i in range(cuent):
            low.remove('delete')

        output_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
        csv_output = csv.writer(output_buffer, delimiter=",")
        for i in low:
            csv_output.writerow([i])
        result = output_buffer.getvalue()
```

Any ideas? The size of the blob in this case is not that large (3MB), and even if I don't read it in directly I will have to save a list with the same size.

Comment: The traceback you posted indicates that the code is failing in the line for k in liwkws:, which has nothing to do with blobstore, is just the query. Can you explain some more what you are doing. Consider also switching to ndb.

Comment: Well I am reading in the file and a list from the datastore - then I compare the two lists to see if items from List A are in items from List B to then delete them. Say List A has "Nike", "Adidas" and "Reebok" and List B has "sneakers", "Nike sneakers", "Adidas sneakers", then items 2 and 3 from List B should be "deleted". Hope this helps?